# Jetson Nano GPIO interrupt lagging

Tags: python, interrupt, gpio, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using the Jetson nano GPIO to read the output of an AB bi-phase rotational encoder encode, I wrote a simple python script to trigger a rising edge interrupt, the callback function prints the current state of the pin that triggered.

```
import time
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO

# Define the GPIO pins for the rotary encoders
PIN = 13

# Initialize GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(PIN, GPIO.IN)

def callback(PIN):
    print(GPIO.input(PIN))
        

# Add event detection for rising edges on all encoder pins
GPIO.add_event_detect(PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback, bouncetime=1)
try:
    while True:
        pass
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
# Clean up GPIO
GPIO.cleanup()
```

After a lot of debugging and many many tries, I stopped using the actual encoder, I'm using a function generator set to output a 3.3v 500hz square wave on pin 13 on the Jetson nano. The output I expect should a stream of ones, but the actual output is random mix of ones and zeros.

> The actual output from the terminal:
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1

What am I missing or doing wrong.

This my system:
L4T 32.6.1 JetPack 4.6
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Kernel Version: 4.9.253-tegra